# Python Socket Chat Room Is Not Working With Ngrok

Tags: python, sockets, multiplayer, ngrok

So lately I have been trying to get into multiplayer with Python. The game I have an idea for is like Dwarf Fortress but with two players instead of AI. To do this I have been looking at a lot of tutorials but none of them are helpful. One I found I just copied and pasted the code for editing later. It is very bad code, but I plan of making it look good when I can get it to work. The program works fine by itself but when I host the port with Ngrok with the command "ngrok.exe tcp 1234" and have me and my friend who are on different wi-fi's try the chat room, it crashes the client. Please help. I know this was not the very best explanation on what's happening but ask any questions you might need to help me and I will answer them.

```html
#SERVER
#Import
from time import *
from socket import *

#Tell The User That They Are Setting Up The Server
print('Setup Server...')
sleep(1)

#Set Socket Stuff
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

hostName = gethostname()
IP = gethostbyname(hostName)
port = int(input("What is the port: "))

#Set Up Server
s.bind((hostName,port))

#Ask User To Put In Username
name = input("Enter Username: ")

#Tries To Locate Client
s.listen(1)
print('Waiting for incoming connections...')

#Accepts Client If It Gets It
connection,addr = s.accept()
print("Received connection from ",addr[0], "(",addr[1],")\n")
print('Connection Established. Connected From: {}, ({})'.format(addr[0],addr[0]))

#Gets The Connection From Client Side
clientName = connection.recv(1024)
clientName = clientName.decode()
print(clientName + ' has connected.')
print('Press [bye] to leave the chat room')
connection.send(name.encode())

#Game Loop
while True:
   message = input('Me > ')
   if message == '[bye]':
      message = 'Good Night...'
      connection.send(message.encode())
      print("\n")
      break
   connection.send(message.encode())
   message = connection.recv(1024)
   message = message.decode()
   print(clientName, '>', message)






#CLIENT
import time, socket, sys
print('Client Server...')
time.sleep(1)

#Get the hostname, IP Address from socket and set Port
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
shost = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(shost)
port = int(input("Put port here: "))

#get information to connect with the server
print(shost, '({})'.format(ip))
server_host = input('Enter server\'s IP address:')
name = input('Enter Client\'s name: ')
#port = 1234
print('Trying to connect to the server: {}, ({})'.format(server_host, port))
time.sleep(1)
soc.connect((server_host, port))
print("Connected...\n")
soc.send(name.encode())
server_name = soc.recv(1024)
server_name = server_name.decode()
print('{} has joined...'.format(server_name))
print('Enter [bye] to exit.')
while True:
   message = soc.recv(1024)
   message = message.decode()
   print(server_name, ">", message)
   message = input(str("Me > "))
   if message == "[bye]":
      message = "Leaving the Chat room"
      soc.send(message.encode())
      print("\n")
      break
   soc.send(message.encode())
```

Comment: So I figured out a few problems. One is that the code has a problem. I fixed that. Second is that when running through Ngrok whatever messages are sent through seems to be coming up with the last message at the same time. Breaking the game. I am going to try and put a time delay so maybe it won't have this problem.

Comment: YES! So I put a 0.1 second delay in the time the server sent the client id and username to the client. Now ngrok doesn't seem to jumble them up like it did before! YES YES YES!

Comment: Sidebar, but you can easily and programmatically manage `ngrok` from Python application using `pyngrok`. TCP Socket example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#python-tcp-server-and-client).